# How to use Esri custom geographic transformation in FME Desktop 2015 Workbench?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, fme-form

I am trying to reproject DWG files from one projection system to other using a custom transformation created by me with ArcGIS.

When I execute it reprojects the data but does not use the custom transformation parameters.

Comment: How are you projecting the data? Which transformer? Are you using the esri transformer?

Comment: yes, esri transformer

Comment: probably a good one to contact the support team about (safe.com/support) - please post an answer here if you get one